# Manipulating Data on 2nd page after button was triggered on 1st page via Console Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to manipulate data on the 2nd page after triggering button onclick() on 1st page. Is there a way in javascript or jquery to wait for the 2nd page to load first before calling an element on it? All of the commands are just being ran on browser console by the way.

I tried to use a setTimeout function to wait for the 2nd page to load and change a combobox's value but it didn't work.

```
//actions done on first page
document.getElementsByName("txtAcctName")[0].value = "ABC";
document.getElementsByName("txtId")[0].value = "0300275777";
document.getElementsByName("Action")[0].click();/*button click trigger which directs to 2nd page*/

setTimeout(function(){/*action to be done on 2nd page*/
    document.getElementsByName("cbomonthyear")[0].selectedIndex = 1;
},1000);
```

Comment: Not like this, no.  When a browser navigates to a new page, all the javascript on the 1st page stops running and is completely discarded.   If you "load" the 2nd page via an ajax call, then the js will continue (and you can use the load callback / ajax promise).  Or you'll have to "pass" some information across such as via the url or local storage.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Its clear now why other commands were not being triggered after loading another page.

I found a way using VBA and IE automation instead since I'm not sure if the website even supports ajax and I don't really have any experience with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
window.onload = function() {
  find_element_and_update();
};
```

Comment: Could you check this fiddle? -- https://jsfiddle.net/hv6Lep2m/.

I have set the dropdown to the second option [starts at 0] on page load.

Comment: that was actually a same page processing, what i needed was to navigate thru another page and change the value of the controls on the 2nd page. Thanks for the effort tho.

Comment: On the second page, if you add an .onload() handler to the script which loads along, you could make it work. But via browser console, you cannot do much because whatever you load gets flushed once the page refreshes. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[name="Action"]').first().on( "click", { value: 1 }, function( event ) {

document.getElementsByName("cbomonthyear")[0].selectedIndex = event.data.value;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way using VBA and IE automation instead since I'm not sure if the website even supports ajax and I don't really have any experience with ajax.